# Find the nth count-and-say sequence element

Tags: c, string, algorithm

```
Given a problem, the count-and-say sequence is the sequence of integers beginning as     follows:
1, 11, 21, 1211, 111221, ...
```

1 is read off as "one 1" or 11.
11 is read off as "two 1s" or 21.
21 is read off as "one 2, then one 1" or 1211.
Given an integer n, generate the nth sequence.

I have made the solution as by scanning each string and generating next string accordingly
It takes time as O(nm)
where m is the length of the largest string
and n is the number given

Here it the code

```
void countnsay(char str[][1000],int n)
{
int i=1,k;
int j=0;
while(i<=(n-1))
{
//scan str[i-1]
j=0;
k=0;        //for building the new string array 
while(j<strlen(str[i-1]) )
    {
    char c=str[i-1][j];
    int cnt=1;

    while(c==str[i-1][++j])
    cnt++;

    str[i][k++]=cnt+48;
    str[i][k++]=c;

    }
str[i][k]='\0';
i++;

}
printf("%s",str[n-1]);  
}




int main()
{
int n=5;
char str[1000][1000];
strcpy(str[0],"1");
countnsay(str,n);
return 0;
}
```

Could there be a more better solution to this problem?
Please give some suggestions/hints.
Thanx in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use dynamic programming. After some time, you'll encounter already existing substrings which were already computed. You can keep a map of already computed sequences:

```
1 -> 11
11 -> 21
```

Now you need to compute `1211`.

You first go for `1`, which you already know is `11`.

The you encounter `2`. You don't have this, so compute `12` and add it to the map:

```
2 -> 12
```

The you encounter `11`, which, again, you have in your map as `21`.

Concatenate these and you get

```
111221
```

and the new map

```
1 -> 11
11 -> 21
2 -> 12
```

EDIT: You only look for consecutive identical numbers, so only keep those in the map.

Comment: what will be the time complexity of this?

Comment: @Luv Should be close to linear, but not sure.

Comment: how would you use the strings as indixes in an array, i mean to say that there may be collision or else the space complexity will be very high.

Comment: @Luv I wouldn't use an array, but some sort of search tree. C doesn't have built-in support for a hashing mechanism.

Comment: I don't think this is the right answer, to be honest, because at the time you know you'd look for '111', you already know the answer is '31', so caching here is not needed. What's really interesting is at some point this string repeats itself and there's a (relative) constant speed of expansion.

Answer (score -1):

```py
def count_and_say(n):
    string= '1'
    for i in range(n-1):
        count = 1
        result = ''
        for j in range(len(string)):
            if j == len(string)-1 or string[j]!=string[j+1]:
                result += str(count)+string[j]
                count = 1
            else:
                count+=1
        string = result
    return string
n = int(input())
print(count_and_say(n))
```

Comment: Please consider adding some context to your answer